# phpbb related session question / cookie

Tags: phpbb

i have one user which is being thrown out from time to time trying to post an article on the phpbb3 forum.
all other users are fine.
i presume its some problems with their cookies but she doesnt have any problem on any other forums.
have any idea?
i just told her to try a different browser to test it.

Comment: Tried clearing the cookies, Different Browsers, Diff systems?

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate on what you mean by "thrown out"? I've had users report that they keep getting *logged* out for no reason, but this was on phpBB2.

Since this was only happening to 1 or 2 users, I just concluded that they were probably running some kind of spyware remover, and that they were probably deleting their own browser cookies not knowing what those cookies actually do. It doesn't make sense that a bug would repeatedly happen to the exact same user when there are thousands of other users who aren't having any problems at all.

But then again, I did recently have an issue with one of phpBB2's tables spontaneously being cleared and having an underscore appended to its name, preventing people from creating any new topics for about a week. I still have no explanation for how that could have happened.

Edit: In response to the new information about proxies & IP changes, you should take a look at [this support thread](http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=767295):

> *Perhaps vbulettin and other boards are rejecting my browser because my network is changing IPs constantly while you're online (this maybe the reason behind this).*
>
> #### Answer:
>
> IP address is part of the sessionhash, so a rapidly changing IP address will invalidate your session and leave you logged out "if" bbuserid & bbpassword are not available to establish a new authenticated session when the address change occurs.

So it looks like if they have "Remember my login/password" checked when they log in, they should haven no problem. There should also be an admin option in phpBB3 to disable the IP binding.

Otherwise, they're going to have to choose a Proxy that doesn't change their IP address so frequently.

Comment: i found out whats going on the user is switching IP addresses on a proxy. PHPBB3 doesnt like that. how to circumvent the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In the phpBB security settings, you can change the amount of the IP address that is validated. AOL in particular is notorious for sending requests from a different proxy every time. Just reduce the security to allow the last two numbers of the IP address to change.